# Deleting the duplicate files made from iTunes - consolidate feature

Tags: macos, itunes

I selected the iTunes folder library as [home folder]/Music

Having music files in the same folder ([home folder]/Music) I select  File -> Organize Library -> Consolidate Files.

Which created doubled files.[image: Image 1]

Every new file have " 1" suffix

[image: Image 2]

How can I delete them ?

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal (Spotilght -> type "Terminal")

Go to Music folder and execute

```
cd ~/Music
find ./ -name "* 1.*" -exec rm {} \;
```

Execute earlier

```
find ./ -name "* 1.*"
```

To check if it find appropriate files.

After this the easiest way would be delete your whole library, and relocate all files again.
(You will lost the data like "how many times you played that song")